# Why shallots over onions?

Tags: shallots

It seems that in more advanced cookbooks and when watching professional chefs that shallots are used extensively. They seem to be used in the places where onions are in cookbooks which are aimed at home cooks.

I am familiar with the genetic similarities between onions and shallots. I have not personally cooked with shallots because they cost an order of magnitude more than onions.

If it is not just my misperception that shallots are preferred- what qualities do shallots have that make them more popular than onions?
Should I expect shallots to be much more expensive than onions or am I shopping at the wrong places?
In short- are they worth paying more for?

Comment: If you have access to a warehouse store (Sam's, Cocso, etc...) keep an eye out. Every once in a while I find bags of shallots at those places for a price rather like onions bought at the grocery store. Then you can try the for a reasonable price.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Shallots certainly aren't more *popular* than onions, otherwise they'd be far more abundant and less expensive.

I do cook with shallots from time to time and would describe them as most people describe them - as somewhere between the flavour of garlic and onion, but also a good deal milder/sweeter.

I prefer to use them simply when I do not want the strong taste of onions.  In fact, many of us are so accustomed to the harsh taste of onions that it's actually quite a surprise to find out how much better a certain dish might taste by substituting shallots.

They're especially common in Asian cooking, I find.  Very often you're providing a lot of spice or heat from other ingredients - chilies, five spice, curry powder, etc. - and don't want the overwhelming pungency of onions mixed in.  Shallots give just a *little bit* of "sharpness" without much of the sulfur taste.

Would I substitute them *everywhere?*  Absolutely not.  Some recipes really do call for the pungency of onions, for example almost anything involving ground beef.  But try it at least once - get yourself a bag of shallots and try substituting them for onions in a few recipes.  You may be pleasantly surprised.

I would say that ideal recipes to try this on, if you're unfamiliar with shallots, are stovetop recipes calling for a relatively small amount of chopped or sliced (not minced) onion; stir fries are ideal, which perhaps is why they seem to be so common in Asian cuisine.

Also, as far as pricing is concerned: Locally, where a 2 lb bag of onions might cost $1.99, a 1 lb bag of shallots would cost $1.49, which makes them roughly 50% more expensive, very far from an "order of magnitude."  If you meant that literally and are finding them close to 10x more expensive than onions, then you are either shopping at the wrong stores or living in an area where they are hard to find.  Try an Asian grocery store if you have one; they can usually be found for dirt cheap in those.

Comment: We have a Korean market - [H-Mart](http://www.hmart.com/), it's a chain, might be able to find one near you - that sells shallots for the same price per pound as our regular grocery sells onions for.

Comment: you called me out on my hyperbole. The shallots at my grocery store are around 3-4x not 10x. I'll take a look in the local asian grocery stores. Thanks!

Comment: @Soba: Still pretty expensive.  If you can't find a local store then I think a lot of the online grocery stores have better pricing.

Comment: As mentioned they're not 10x more but they do cost more for less.  They're often used when an oniony (that is so a word!) flavor is desired but not the full on blast you get from a full onion.

Comment: I finally went to an Asian grocery store and found shallots for about the same prices that you mentioned above. Looking forward to trying them out.

Comment: Regular onions are damaging to people that have weak digestive systems, and so for some shallots is their only choice, because the enzymes in them are different.

Comment: Considering onions are quite cheap, and that shallots have a pretty strong taste, meaning you don't need to use as many of them as onions, the markup isn't all that bad. Plus you can always *mix*, say, 1 small shallot, 1 big onion.

Comment: I like this answer but I take exception to the comment that shallots are less hot than onions. It depends SIGNIFICANTLY on what kind of onion. There are white, yellow and red onions, going from sweeter to hotter in that list, and then time of year also affects the heat of the onion, with spring onions being really sweet and late summer and fall onions being really hot. In fact there are charts to help you decide which onion to pick depending on the color and time of year. Vidalia onions are available most in the spring because that's when white onions are sweet and no one wants a hot Vidalia.

Comment: @Escoce - I agree. Also depends a lot on the shallots. Thai red shallots are incredibly pungent, peppery and slightly bitter, compare them to white onions which seem almost bland in comparison. To summarise - i think the differences are more in flavour profile than in strength/potency

Answer (score 6):

The Simple answer: try them. If you like a milder taste which is vaguely like a spoiled onion, you might enjoy them.

- They don't taste like garlic.
- They have a taste which is similar to onion, but there is a slight sour note to them.

I have heard them referred to as onions for people who don't like onions (though I have no idea what that would mean). However, if you just want a very mild sweet onion, use a Peruvian, Vidalia, or perhaps a Maui onion. I would prefer any of these to a shallot.

Comment: I like them for milder sauces.  I have also started using them in salsa/guacamole.  They give some of the onion taste and crunch I am looking for, but milder.

Comment: Just to add, as a child I hated onions, but in my adolescence I slowly came to realise that onions weren't so bad and started with, who would have guessed, shallots. So "onions for people who don't like onions" held true for me.

Answer (score 4):

I personally cook 90% of my meals with shallots. Most people keep onions at home on a consistent basis, i keep shallots. If you don't like onions, this is the perfect substitute in cooked meals. They are very mild but have a distinct flavor that everyone likes. However, in certain meat dishes and some stocks, clearly you would need onions for a stronger flavor and presence.

I have even used shallots as substitutes for onions in salads. 
When doing this I use VERY little (1/4 bulb) as they are very strong when uncooked. Also, because of the distinct hint of garlic- like flavor, I only pair with certain other vegetables in my mix.

In supermarkets, the price of shallots is pretty high. I live in NJ and have seen two bulbs for almost $2-3. I go to produce stores that sell bulk and get a 1-2lb. bag for $2.

Answer (score 3):

I CANNOT eat onions in any form.  I must read labels on everything and be especially cautious in restaurants.  I was delighted to discover shallots after years of no onions (I ate onions with no problem until I was 22 years old and loved them -- then developed an intolerance).  I have no difficulty with leeks, garlic or shallots.  An onion contains some component not common to the other three and leeks and shallots can often be substituted.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts.

Shallots are easy to grow so that is not a reason not to use them.

They require more work per pound of delivered vegetable but if you plunge them into water that has just boiled, for a minute or two, it is much easier to peel them (this also applies to pickling onions). Proper chefs of course have a KP to do the dirty work.

Some food is better for the conformation of them. For example, coq au vin should have identifiable cooked shallots in it (imho, ymmv).  Incidentally, CAV is also well made using pheasants. You do have pheasants, don't you?

Comment: I was a 16 year old KP. I got to work at 5 PM, my first task nightly was to mince a dozen shallots, and mince3 bulbs of garlic. They were kept in oil at the line cook station. I developed some great knife handling skills there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a  cook book about Burma cusine. There I came to know about shallots. It mention that frying shallots slices in oil will give two out puts. Crispy shallot chips and residual oil 
after straining to use for salad dressing or soup.

It was first time I heard about shallots and never tasted fried chips of shallots and using flavoured oil instead a fresh one in salads or soup or dishes.

Some sects in India have clear disfavours to onions. Shallots are milder and can be used if 
onions are banned.

Answer (score 1):

A few very trivial but valid reasons: They are easier to dice very finely, they cook much quicker (especially when finely diced :) ), and they are small so you don't have to concern yourself with how to store or dispose of 3/4 of a cut onion if all you need is 1/4 onion.

The very small asian-type shallots are also much denser when it comes to flavor content vs water content - which is very helpful if one is making traditional thai/indonesian/... spice pastes in a mortar (extra water and extra plant matter bulk makes it more difficult, and also increases spoilage risk).