# Are shallots less gas-producing than yellow onion?

Tags: onions, shallots

I realise the answer's probably subjective and might vary among individuals but in your experience, have you found cooking with shallots to be less 'gassy' than using yellow onions?

I'm not allergic to alliums but I become very gassy from them. Even a small amount of onion powder will give me very malodorous gas - fine if I'm alone for the next 24-36 hours. I cook Asian dishes and use a small amount of green onion. While I still have gas, it's less than regular onion.

Please don't suggest asafoetida as I've used it before and didn't think it made a good substitute. It also wouldn't suit the soups and stews I normally use onion in.

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40348

Comment: @András Salamon I'm shopping today and will pick up a few shallots to try them. Unlike the OP from the link you gave, all allium produce gas for me. Still, hopefully shallots might be less than onions.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty subjective but I find shallots are right up there with onions (particularly red onions). Of course, not all shallots are created equal, e.g. banana shallots tend to be stronger in both flavour and 'gaseous effect'.

(If you haven't already) I'd suggest trying:

- Leeks
- [Scapes](http://theculturedcook.com/2010/06/scapes-ramps-and-other-wild-alliums/)
- Wild garlic (if you are in an area where it can be foraged)
- Even [fennel](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2013/mar/30/best-foods-for-ibs) when cooked long enough (it loses the anise flavour) has been known as a decent substitute